# Can we run one half of a test on a given day and the second half on the next day using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

We have some application functionality where we have the user create an item. This item expires at midnight. So if the user tries again the next day the system recreates the item in the backend, but the user will be shown the new item. Our automation test framework is Selenium. 
Two options came to my mind

1) Update the database so that the item expires immediately and execute the second step. -> The issue is that we do not have access to the database from the automation test framework. Also, I think this is not a true test because we are expiring the item and not waiting for the system to expire the item. So we are not testing if the item expires.

2) Add a wait time of 1 day in the test case -> This means that the thread will wait for 1 day or at least a few hours.

Is there another way to do this ? Please suggest

Comment: Make it possible to mock the current time. Then you can make the test behave as if it were midnight anytime.

Comment: It sound like you are looking for a devops tool like Jenkins.

Comment: Using Jenkins like guy said would be beneficial, you can use Tags to run them with NUnit and then you can just make specific Tags run in a given time.

Comment: We do have jenkins already but the case I am looking for is timebound. Example : Assume we have a user who gets a token valid for one day. My test case should be able to generate the token on day 1 and check if the token expired on day 2.  Can this be achieved using Selenium.

Comment: I'm also looking for similar solution. Have you found any solution?